# analog to digital converter as voltmeter

Tags: adc, voltmeter

I'm still student so excuse me if the question is not professional. 
Basically ADC can convert any voltage within decided range to the digital form.

Isn't that what exactly the digital voltmeter does?

Why do we need the complicated circuit of digital voltmeter if only ADC is enough to do the job for us?

Comment: How are you going to read the converted voltages? What voltage limits can you measure while keeping a good precision (1mV up to 600V AC and DC)? How are you going to supply it? What about the voltage reference you compare your voltage to? Is your input protected?... All this and possibly more was integrated in product so that you won't need to deal with it.

Comment: "Isn't that what exactly the digital voltmeter does?" - Yes, but it does a lot more than just that - ADC is just one stage. Its like saying "an engine converts petrol to movement  so is that exactly what a car does? Why do we need gears and clutch, suspension, brakes, steering etc?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connect a 5V ADC to 120VAC, you will likely have a rather violent puff of smoke. The circuitry of a digital voltmeter is for scaling and protection: it scales a wide variety of voltages in ranges to fit a single range of voltages that is most optimal for the single ADC internal to the voltmeter. This circuitry is also responsible for making sure that no harm comes to the operator or device in the event that the device is connecting to high potentials or otherwise misused.

A typical ADC used in a DMM might have a resolution of 16 - 20+ bits and an input voltage range of zero to a few volts. Clearly, such a converter cannot directly convert hundreds of volts, nor can it accurately convert very small voltages directly. Thus, additional circuitry is required.

Comment: Wouldn't setting a digital multimeter to 5V range and connecting it to 120 V result in a similar puff of smoke?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Most (almost all?) DMM will autorange - accurately read a 500mV signal and then a 100V signal a moment later. Enjoy designing a front-end for your ADC that does the same!

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Only on a very poorly built DMM :) A decent DMM will have clamp circuitry to protect the input from voltages outside of the range, and good DMM (as DoxyLover points out) will autorange: it dynamically varies the input scaling and clamping based on the input signal.

Comment: @DoxyLover You have mistaken me for the OP, I'm not designing anything.

Answer (score 3):

Bluntly, User Interface.  The DMM has an ADC in it, and it has plenty of interface hardware that correctly scales the input for the ADC, provides an excitation voltage to facilitate resistance and capacitance measurements, reference resistors to allow current measurements, glue to drive the LCD display, etc.

Even if you were to just use and ADC, you would still need to build a display, or use a computer screen to know what the ADC were telling you.

I can buy a cheap DMM for about $5 USD.

As for "enough to do the job for us", that depends entirely on what job you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Volt meters are also calibrated to some degree to another voltage source, ADC's are not. ADC's also need "complicated circuitry" to read the range of voltages that a DMM or analog meter can. ADC's can only read voltages, DMM's can also convert current to a voltage.

DMM's also have other functions like peak to peak and RMS.